# How do you resize text boxes without resizing the text?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, resize

Unfortunately, questions that were previously asked about this do not resolve this issue. After I convert a text box to paragraph text, it still resizes the text when I resize the text box, just like it is expected to do with point text. I verified that the text is truly paragraph text and not point text by right-clicking the layer in the layers dialog, and the Type-> Convert To... in the upper navigation bar.

I'm using Adobe Photoshop Version: 2017.0.1 20161130.r.29 2016/11/30:23:00:00 CL 1099099  x64.

Does anyone know the up-to-date answer to this question?

related post: [Photoshop: how to resize a text box without distorting the actual text?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42095/how-do-i-resize-my-text-box-in-photoshop-without-distorting-the-actual-text/51050)

Comment: Could you describe in detail how you are resizing the text box?

Comment: As far as I know the answer hasn't changed. If you cmd/ctrl+t to transform then it will resize the text, if you just resize the frame while it is active it will only resize the frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I resize my text box in Photoshop without distorting the actual text?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/42095/how-do-i-resize-my-text-box-in-photoshop-without-distorting-the-actual-text)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. "questions that were previously asked about this do not resolve this issue" covers that question. I believe this is a bug that occurs and reopening photoshop fixes it.

Comment: What happens if you convert it to 'Area Type'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After closing and reopening the program, the paragraph-text functionality returned. It may be a bug but it is NOT a feature change. Close this question.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer to stop the answer showing up as "unanswered".

Answer (score 0):

If you make an empty text box and type or paste text into it you can resize the box and the text stays the same size.
If you click the text tool and type or paste text, when you resize the text box the text resizes.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the text tool when resizing your text box. If you scale down or stretch the text box using select tool, this affects text also.

Answer (score 0):

To keep type the same size, use the text tool while enlarging a type box, not the move tool.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/113728)